# How to simplify this code using .net 3.5/C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5

I have the following code in `C# and .net 3.5` that is working fine but need to know if this can be simplified may be using Linq or something else? Basically I am reading a xml file to get the column names. And then try to copy the columns and the sequence attribute in a dictionary object if "isactive attribute of the column is "true". I use this dictionary object in other part of code. I loop through elements and then attributes and look for the columns that are active, if active I store the sequence and finally add the column and the sequence to the dictionary.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("DataStructure.xml");
var cols = doc.XPathSelectElements("/datastructure/" + sPageName + "/columns");
Dictionary<string, int> columns = new Dictionary<string, int>();
bool bAddData = true;
int sSequence = 0;

foreach (var col in cols.Elements())
{
    foreach (XAttribute at in col.Attributes())
    {
        if (at.Name.ToString().ToLower().Equals("isactive") && at.Value.ToString() != "true")
        {
            bAddData = false;
            break;
        }

        bAddData = true;                    
        if (at.Name.ToString().ToLower().Equals("sequence"))
        {
            sSequence = Convert.ToInt32(at.Value.ToString());
            break;
        }
    }
    if (bAddData)
    {
        columns.Add(col.Name.ToString(), sSequence);
    }
}
```

I am sure this is pretty poor code but I would like to know how can I improve it. Here is the xml data file. I am ok if I need to restructure the xml to make this simple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<datastructure>
  <MyPage>
    <columns>
      <number isactive="true" sequence="1" />
      <curr_code isactive="true" sequence="2" />
      <curr_desc isactive="true" sequence="3" />
      <tradecurrvalue isactive="true" sequence="4" />
      <selectcurrvalue isactive="true" sequence="5" />
    </columns>    
  </MyPage>
</datastructure>
```

Comment: Why? You already have 'faster than LINQ' version of your code.

Comment: @BoltClock, C# 3.5. I thought I am not fully utilizing C# 3.5.

Comment: @Mrchief, I thought LINQ can simplify but may be it will be slower and less flexible. Am I right?

Comment: @user465876: C# 3.5 doesn't exist. It's either 3.0 or 4.0...

Comment: It may reduce the number of lines of code and produce shorter syntax, but it does introduce overhead. Ultimately it'll be translated to `foreach` at some point. LINQ combined with lambdas does produce elegant code. Is it simpler? That's subjective!

Comment: @Mrchief, hmm, yes - it is really subjective. I guess using LINQ and lambdas, the code look neat and as you say elegant.

Comment: OP means C# 3.0 on .NET 3.5 (since Query Extensions aren't available on .NET 2.0/3.0) (Sorry, not enough rep to comment.)

Comment: @BoltClock, sorry for the confusion.. I meant .net 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this should do it:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("DataStructure.xml");
var cols = doc.XPathSelectElements("/datastructure/" + sPageName + "/columns");

Dictionary<string, int> columns =
  cols.Elements()
  .Where(c => c.Attribute("isactive").Value == "true")
  .ToDictionary(
    c => c.Name.ToString(),
    c => Int32.Parse(c.Attribute("sequence").Value)
  );
```

#### Edit:

Out of curiosity I wanted to find out what could be done about the original code without using LINQ once I figured out what it acutally did and how to best use the methods in the `XElement` class, and I arrived at this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("DataStructure.xml");
var cols = doc.XPathSelectElements("/datastructure/" + sPageName + "/columns");
Dictionary<string, int> columns = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var col in cols.Elements()) {
  if (col.Attribute("isactive").Value == "true") {
    columns.Add(col.Name.ToString(), Int32.Parse(col.Attribute("sequence").Value));
  }
}
```

Comment: I find this so much harder to read than the original version.

Comment: @Charles: I actually find it easier to follow. It took me a while to figure out what the original code was doing. I also simplified it a bit now, using the methods in the XElement to find the attribute instead of LINQ extensions.

Comment: lol @ Guffa. You find it easier to follow? Dude, you wrote the code. I would you find it easy to follow, if only for that reason.

Comment: @Tundey: Writing it as a query makes it more straight forward. The original code is actually overly complicated, so it could also be made more readable without LINQ.

Comment: I don't think this works correct.  The c.Attribute("isactive").Value != "true" should be c.Attribute("isactive").Value == "true".

Comment: @Michael: I already made that change. :) It first was an expression with `Any` that made an negative check like the original code, and the `!=` was left when I changed that.

Comment: @Guffa: To each their own - I guess just haven't got used to reading Linq and Lambdas yet (I'm a late adopter :)). If I actually used this style of syntax a lot more, I'd probably eventually start finding it more readable. But from the get-go I've always found it unfriendly. Too entrenched in my imperative ways, I guess.

Comment: @Guffa: I wasn't commenting on that part. Just commenting on you saying you find what *you* wrote easier to follow. That's the funny part...to me anyway.

Comment: @Guffa, appreciate your curiosity which made me think what did I code:). Your simplified code with XElement is what I was looking for. GREAT!! Now, who needs LINQ - Lols. But, I must say LINQ is definitely more readable and am using it in some other places. But I need to learn a lot about LINQ to fully utilize the power of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("DataStructure.xml");
var cols = doc.XPathSelectElements("/datastructure/MyPage/columns").Descendants();
var columns = cols.Where(e => e.Attribute("isactive").Value.ToLower() == "true").ToDictionary(e => e.Name, e => int.Parse(e.Attribute("sequence").Value));
```

Comment: I found this solution to be short and very elegant. Wondering if there are any limitations btw this and other solutions provided above.

Comment: I don't think so.  However if your not always going to have isactive, you will have to check for that in the where clause.  Stuff like that you may have to tweak to make it production ready.  That all depends on your incoming xml and what attributes are required.

Comment: the xml is a configuration file and will always have all the attributes with value/null.

Comment: I would rate this solution high but will keep this LINQ solution for future use. I will right now go with my code but a simplified version posted by Guffa :) Thanks Miachael for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
cols.Elements().Where(
                e =>
                    {
                        var attribute = e.Attribute("isactive");
                        return attribute != null &&
                               attribute.Value.ToString().Equals("true", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                    })
                .ToDictionary(e => e.Name.ToString(),
                              e => Convert.ToInt32(e.Attribute("sequence").Value.ToString()));
```

Comment: @bdowden: Why would you care about `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` here? Is tiny speed optimization worth additional four lines of code? Just curious.

Comment: I'm used to working in a multi-lingual system. I put it in just because I'm used to doing it.